# Laravel group by with Elequent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working with Laravel and Eloquent ORM and after developing controller,model and view for my table I need to extract agregate informations but I don't figure out wich is the best way or the cleanest "Laravel" way to do that.

I have a db **table** like this example :

```
Schema::create('order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('item_description');
        $table->integer('item_qty');
        $table->status('item_status');
    });
```

The detail **data** can be like:

```
2   2017-02-28 12:48:07 2017-02-28 12:48:31 1   ProductB    2   NEW
4   2017-02-28 12:48:17 2017-02-28 12:48:17 1   ProductC    3   NEW
29  2017-03-10 10:49:47 2017-03-10 10:49:47 1   ProductC    23  CLOSED
40  2017-03-10 10:49:47 2017-03-10 10:49:47 1   ProductB    2   SHIPPED
1   2017-02-28 11:04:28 2017-02-28 11:29:10 3   ProductA    1   NEW
28  2017-03-10 10:49:47 2017-03-10 10:49:47 3   ProductB    22  CLOSED
39  2017-03-10 10:49:47 2017-03-10 10:49:47 3   ProductA    1   SHIPPED
5   2017-02-28 14:36:54 2017-02-28 14:36:54 6   ProductD    4   NEW
6   2017-02-28 14:37:01 2017-02-28 14:37:01 6   ProductD    5   NEW
30  2017-03-10 10:49:47 2017-03-10 10:49:47 6   ProductD    24  CLOSED
41  2017-03-10 10:49:47 2017-03-10 10:49:47 6   ProductC    3   SHIPPED
```

In the **controller** I use a scope

```
public function home()
{
  $onlynew = Orderitem::onlynew ();
  return view('home', compact('onlynew '));
}
```

The **model** is

```
public function scopeonlynew ($query) {
return \DB::select('SELECT item_description, sum(item_qty) qty 
                    FROM   order_items 
                    WHERE item_status = ? 
                    GROUP BY item_description',['NEW']);
}
```

In the view I can access data in this way

```
<div class="row">
 <ul>
  @foreach ($onlynew as $newitem)
   <li>{{$newitem->item_description}} - {{$newitem->qty}}</li>
  @endforeach
 </ul>
</div>
```

Is it possible to use a syntax like the following *example* or for this kind of query the framework do not allow to use the builder?

```
return $query->where('item_status', '=', 'NEW')
         ->sum('item_qty')
         ->groupBy('item_description')
         ->orderBy('item_description');
```

Thanks for any kind of help or suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `sum()` method it executes the query and returns just the sum. What you want here is to get the aggregate sum AND the description so you have to build the select yourself. This is what the "Laravel" way might look like.

Controller:

```
public function home()
{
    $onlynew = Orderitem::onlyNew()->get();
    return view('home', compact('onlynew '));
}
```

Model:

```
public function scopeOnlyNew($query) 
{
    return $query->where('item_status', '=', 'NEW')
        ->selectRaw('sum(item_qty) as qty, item_description')
        ->groupBy('item_description')
        ->orderBy('item_description');
}
```

Note the query scope is built a little differently. [Query scopes are designed to allow you to group commonly use query constraints into a single method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) then reuse those constraints with whatever query you're building. They should always return the same query object that they are given instead of creating a new one like `DB::select()`.

Comment: **selectRaw** was exactly what I was looking for and the piece of documentation that I miss. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to use the DB::table statement.

```
public function scopeonlynew () {
    return DB::table('order_items')->where('item_status', '=','NEW')->get();
}
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: I agree with you that the DB::table statement that you suggest works but this is a "filter" that return a detailed result, how can group and aggregate? Thanks.

Comment: return     DB::table('order_items')->where('item_status','=','NEW')>groupBy('item_qt')->having('account_id', '>', 5);

Comment: This is not a scope though. Scopes should return the $query object they are given. This will just create a new query. So if you tried `Orderitem::where('item_description', '=', 'ProductA')->onlynew()` it would not work as expected. It would just return ALL new items instead of just new productA items.

Comment: @jfadich : You are correct indeed I call my scope _onlynew()_ directly from model _Orderitem_ using **Orderitem::onlynew()** and I add filter in the scope. Thanks.

Comment: @DeHazelaar this is not a scope. scopes take Builder as first argument and return it back after manipulation. your scope is returning a Collection.